# Remove whitespace before like-function sql

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

I'm trying to optimize the speed and effectiveness of a search function for our customers. It is coded in SQL using SQL server 2014. It allows them to search for users in the database and should show all users whose names contain the text they put in (e.g. "john" should show both "john hansen" and "hans johnson". As of now it's working well except if our customers put in blank spaces before or after the text, they're searching for ("  john" or "john  ". In that case the system returns nothing..... We're using the like function, and it seems near impossible to work around to get it to ignore whitespace.

The example here:

`a.name LIKE '%example%' OR b.remark LIKE '%example%'`

It's not possible to create a column in sync with the one with the names in which the spaces are removed, as we're not entitled to modify the database itself - only the query. So what I'm wondering if is there's a way to remove the blank spaces in the strings of the column temporarily before applying the like function but in the same select? Or maybe if there's an alternative? I'm really in deep water here as it is also important that the response time of the system remains unchanged or even improves by this modification... Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use `ltrim(rtrim())`:

```
a.name like '%' + ltrim(rtrim('example')) + '%'
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! I'll read up on the function and look into it at work tomorrow and will be back with an update!

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks!